# Add Markers From embedded Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

how can a user add Markers from an embedded Google Map on my homepage to hin own map on google-maps?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are you using the Google Maps API or just embedding a map from maps.google.com. If it's embedding a map from maps.google.com, you can't do what you're proposing.  You can, however, do it using the Google Maps API with some significant coding.  There are also third party solutions that _may_ work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're proposing sounds like a Google My Maps. Go to http://maps.google.com, sign in to a Google account, and click on My Places. Then click on Create Map. You create a map, and embed it in your site. Anyone clicking on a marker created there can save that marker to their own map. Take a look at this [sample map](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=206777747311596925723.0004af7fc50eda575d964&msa=0&ll=37.291535,-121.124268&spn=1.817954,4.22699). Click on the marker for Google and in the infowindow, select Save to map.

Comment: this is what i need, but i need for every user on my page a different map with his friends, how can that be done?

Comment: Is your map different user to user? Or just the one they're copying your places to? If it's the former, you can't. There's no way to programmatically create My Maps at this point. If your map doesn't change, you just need to put in the explanation that they need to copy to a map they share with other users.